# Как стиль ContextMenuMy установить к MenuItem из кода?

Tags: c#, wpf, style

Как стиль ContextMenuMy установить к MenuItem из кода?

```
item = new MenuItem { 
    Background = HexToColorConverter.GetColorFromHex("#FF222222"),
    Foreground = HexToColorConverter.GetColorFromHex("#FFCCCCCC"),
    BorderBrush = HexToColorConverter.GetColorFromHex("#FF222222"),

    Style = (Style)(this.Resources["ContextMenuMy"])//new Style(),
```

Background, Foreground, BorderBrush работают.

> Ошибка    CS1061  'SpellCheckBehavior" не содержит определения для
>   "Resources" и не удалось найти метод расширения "Resources",
>   принимающий тип "SpellCheckBehavior" в качестве первого аргумента
>   (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

К другим элементам стиль ContextMenuMy в XAML применяется таким образом.

```
<TextBlock.ContextMenu >
    <ContextMenu Style="{DynamicResource ContextMenuMy}" >
```

Comment: попробуйте так Style = (Style)FindResource("ContextMenuMy");

Comment: Имя "FindResource" не существует в текущем контексте.

Comment: хм... может так? myControl.SetResourceReference(Control.StyleProperty, "ContextMenuMy")

Comment: а что такое SpellCheckBehavior? У вас же компилятор выдает ошибку, что класс Resources не найден

Comment: Это класс в котором и написана эта строка `Style =`

Comment: Готово. Так работает `textEditor.ContextMenu.SetResourceReference(Control.StyleProperty, "ContextMenuMy");`